# How to display a list of books in Android Studio?

Tags: java, button, scrollview

I'm making an app that presents a list of books to the user. I want to create a page that shows 3 books (the title and the picture) at each row (using buttons) and, using ScrollView, shows the 3 next books etc. Once the user clicks on a book, its summary will appear.
What code should I use on Android Studio and java file?

Comment: CyberShark is correct: this is exactly what  RecyclerView is for.  There are many tutorias, e.g.: http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/android-recyclerview-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Recycler View](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview?hl=en) or [List View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView).